# How do I write a backslash (with Alt+Shift+7) in Xcode without commenting line?

Tags: xcode, keyboard, backslash

How do I write a "\" in Xcode without commenting out the whole line ?

```
var name = "Kevin"
var returnValue = "Hi \(name)"
```

When I type the backslash with alt+shift+7 it comments out the whole line...

```
//var returnValue = "Hello "
```

Comment: Do you mean there's no backslash on your keyboard?

Comment: Perhaps you typed "cmd-/", which is a shortcut for "Comment Selection"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're using a keyboard layout in which you have to type Alt-Shift-7 to type a backslash. (That's not true for the U.S. layout, for example.)

The problem is presumably that Alt-Shift-7 (or some portion of that) is assigned as the keyboard shortcut for the Editor > Structure > Comment Selection menu item. In Xcode's Preferences, you can change the keyboard shortcut assigned to that function (or simply remove the keyboard shortcut) and that should allow the keystroke to behave normally.

Comment: Yes, I am using a german keyboard. I have removed the shortcut and now it works fine! Thank you for your help!
PS: Newbie question: If I wanna for example point out that I DO have a non-US keyboard should I write it here? It's pretty much a "Thank You" what I'm writing here. Since stack overflow tells me to avoid "Thanks" comments.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. I guess one should always give information that they think will help people understand what's going on, but it's not always easy to know what that information is. That information would go in the question, which you can edit even after you've posted it. Anyway, you're welcome.

Comment: You said "I assume you're using a keyboard layout in which you have to type Alt-Shift-7 to type a backslash" so should I answer with "Yes I do have a non-US keyboard, thanks for your answer" or should I just upvote your answer and don't comment anything? Stack overflow says I should avoid "Thanks" comments.

Comment: Accepting the answer is fine, but for the sake of people who come across this question and answer in the future, it's good that you confirmed that you're using a German keyboard layout. It will help them understand what was going on. That's especially true since some people expressed confusion in the comments about why it requires a multi-key keystroke to type a backslash.